# How to parse URL with # in Swift?

Tags: ios, swift, url, nsurl

Suppose, I have following URL: `https://something.com/room/order/12345555/product/543333?is_correct=true`. It is kind of deeplink and I should parse its parameters and show some ViewController. I am interested in values as 12345555, 543333 and true. Actually, it is easy to get those parameters.

In order to get 12345555 or 543333, we can use `pathComponents` of URL which returns `["/", "room", "order", "12345555", "product", "543333"]`. To get query items (is_correct: true), we can use URLComponents. Everything is clear and simple.

But suppose my link contains `#` as path `https://something.com/room/#/order/12345555/product/543333?is_correct=true`. Now, for this link, `pathComponents` returns just `["/", "room"]` ignoring everything else. Of course, there are also problems with query parameters.

Why does `#` symbol affect so? How can I solve problem? Should I just replace `#` with something or `URL` from Swift contains some helper methods? Thanks.

Comment: The `#` symbol represents the [URL fragment](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/URI_fragment)

Comment: You mean that if I call `url.fragment`, it returns everything after #?

Comment: The problem is that `url.fragment` returns String and basically you cannot use convenient things like `pathComponents` and `URLComponents`

Comment: Are you dealing with a situation where `room/#/order` and `room/order` can be used more-or-less interchangeably?  If so something like, `.replacingOccurrences(of: "/#/", with: "/")` could be a reasonable first-step in transformation.  Otherwise, you could do something like `let fragmentUrl = URL(string: url.fragment!, relativeTo: url)!` to get just the stuff after `#`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The problem you're running into is that `#` isn't part of the path but introducing a new component of the URL, stored in `url.fragment`.  It's similar to if you had `https://example.com/foo/?test=/bar`.  `?test=` isn't a path component but the beginning of the query.

You have two approaches you can take.

If `https://something.com/room/order/12345555/product/543333?is_correct=true` and `https://something.com/room/#/order/12345555/product/543333?is_correct=true` can be used interchangeably, as in viewing either page in the browser will land you on the same page, you could have a sanitizing step in your process:

```swift
var rawUrl = ...
var sanitizedUrl = url.replacingOccurrences(of: "/#/", with: "/")
var url = URL(string: url)
```

How much sanitization you do depends on your application.  It could be that you only want to do `(of: "/room/#/", with: "/room/")`

Another option, if you know your fragment will always look like a partial URL would be to pass the fragment into `URL`:

```
let url = URL(string: rawUrl)!
let fragmentUrl = URL(string: url.fragment!, relativeTo: url)!

let fullPathComponents = url.pathComponents + fragmentUrl.pathComponents[1...];
var query = fragmentUrl.query
```

The above approach yields: `["/", "room", "order", "12345555", "product", "543333"]` for the joined URL.

Which approach and how much sanitization you do will depend on your use-case.

Answer (score 1):

###### In the typical case of the app being called-back at a custom URL...

As of 2023, I really don't know a more elegant way to do it, than just

- convert it to a string,
- replace the hash with a query so that the string is a normal url
- convert the string back to a url

Hence,

```
class SceneDelegate: UIResponder, UIWindowSceneDelegate {
    func scene(_ scene: UIScene, openURLContexts: Set<UIOpenURLContext>) {
        if let urlContext = openURLContexts.first {
            process(urlContext.url)
        }
    }
    ...
    ...
```

and then ...

```
///KISS approach, change # to ? then proceed normally.
func process(_ u: URL) {

    let clean = u.absoluteString.replacingOccurrences(of: "#", with: "?")

    if let c = URLComponents(string: clean), let q = c.queryItems {

        let dict = q.reduce(into: [:]) { $0[$1.name] = $1.value }
        print(dict)
    }
}
```

And that's it.

Unfortunately if you use `.fragment` there's no way to make Foundation of the work of parsing it, which is a shame.

I suppose you could say `clean = "z://?\(urlstring.fragment)"` (where the z is just an irrelevant character) but there's no advantage at all and it seems more straightforward and readable to simply swap the # to a ?.